# Can we derive some of eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of $m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a symmetric matrix of order $p$ such that each row of $A$ has $1$ at $m$ places and $2$ at $p-m-1$ places. Diagonal entries of $A$ are zero.

Can we derive some of eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of $m$?

EDIT: I tried a few examples and noticed that eigenvalues are coming as integers and some of eigenvalues are repeating.

Comment: All the row sums are the same, so there is an eigenvalue given by the row sum. For the rest, all you can give in general are estimates (e.g. Gerschgorin estimates) and relationships (e.g. the trace is zero so the sum of the eigenvalues is zero).

Comment: @ lan, when I am trying some examples of this form, some eigenvalues are coming with high multiplicity. I can't figure it out :(

Comment: Multiplicity isn't that surprising in view of Gerschgorin--all the Gershgorin disks in your problem are identical, meaning that your matrix is in some sense a perturbation of the zero matrix.

Comment: Gershgorin disks are identical. How it ensures multiplicity of some evalues?

Comment: It doesn't ensure anything at all; indeed if you add a random amount with total sum zero, absolute value sum constant, and zero diagonal entries to each row, you probably won't have multiplicity anymore. But it makes it possible, because all that Gerschgorin guarantees is that all your eigenvalues are in the disk of radius $m+2p-2m-2$ centered at zero. (Symmetry then guarantees they are real of course).